# After successfully booting w/out install from USB, how to access the same USB?

Tags: boot, usb

Edit: So, I want to boot linux on school computers but that also means I can't install on these computers so I want to run it from my USB. While running ubuntu, my USB that I am booting from is not visible. I hope this is clearer :)

I appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Just to be clear, are you asking about how to mount and view the contents of your USB flash drive after using it to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you asking how to see the installation media, once started in a liveusb?

Comment: As the above comments indicate, please clarify the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Put USB drive in USB port, open the file manager, look under places for your flash drive, click on it.

[image: Forgot that I was using Mint, but the screen shot should be pretty close to what you should see.]

*Forgot that I was using Mint, but the screen shot should be pretty close to what you should see.*

Comment: thanks for the answer! but  i simply don't see the flashdrive that I am booting ubuntu from, am I not suppose to?

Comment: Yes you should be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

When booted from the Live USB you will see the USB contents by going to the folder **filesystem/cdrom.**
This is the folder that contains everything on the FAT32 partition of the flash drive.